# RAM memory used by resources

Tags: java, memory, libgdx

Is there a tool to show me on what memory is used?

Would be great if I can see how much memory consume every resource... 
When I want to measure this I put comment on part of code where I load resources and look at memory usage in Task Manager.

I don't want just this:

```
usedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Want to know how much RAM is spent on resources...

I found this bellow, and I need to know how to measure that "vram" memory?

"If your platform does not have dedicated video memory, is not hardware accelerated, or other uncommon cases, then the next section regarding VRAM will happen completely or partially in RAM, but the main principles will be the same.

Video Memory

This is where your images will be stored once your program is running. In general, the format in which you stored them will make no difference here, as all images are decompressed before loading them into video memory."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check Java Mission Control and Java Flight recorder ([from Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html)). They can be used to monitorize memory usage from different resources of your Java application.